# setCustomView didnot work for tablayout in android studio

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have a `tablayout` with 5 tabs. Each tab has an `icon` and `title`. I want to change color of icon and title for tab that is selected and tab that is **`un-selected`**. For this i try using custom tabs but it didn't work. Here is my code for **`custom_tab.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tabIcon"/>
    <com.prj.shopt.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#C1C1C1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tabTitle"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**and my code in `Home2Activity`:**

```
package com.prj.shopt;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    private TabLayout tabs;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private HomeTabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
    private int[] activeIcons={R.drawable.homeactive,R.drawable.category_highlighted,R.drawable.heart_highlighted,
    R.drawable.basketactive,R.drawable.avatar_highlighted};
    private int[] deactiveIcons={R.drawable.homedeactive,R.drawable.category_default,R.drawable.heart_default,
            R.drawable.basketdeactive,R.drawable.avatar_default};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2);
        tabs=findViewById(R.id.homeTabs);
        viewPager=findViewById(R.id.tabsViewPager);
        setupViewPager();
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }
    private void setupTabIcons(){
        if(tabs.getTabCount()<5)
            return;
        int len=activeIcons.length;
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++) {
            //tabs.getTabAt(j).setIcon(deactiveIcons[j]);
            tabs.getTabAt(j).setCustomView(HomeTabsAdapter.getTabView(deactiveIcons[j], R.color.tab_inactive, "test", Home2Activity.this,tabs));
        }
        tabs.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(HomeTabsAdapter.getTabView(activeIcons[0],R.color.tab_active,"test",Home2Activity.this,tabs));
    }
    private void setupViewPager(){
        tabsAdapter=new HomeTabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        setupFragments();
    }

    private void setupFragments() {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            tabsAdapter.addFragment(new FavFragment(),getResources().getString(R.string.favTab));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //tab.setIcon(activeIcons[tab.getPosition()]);
        tab.setCustomView(HomeTabsAdapter.getTabView(activeIcons[tab.getPosition()],R.color.tab_active,"test",Home2Activity.this,tabs));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //tab.setIcon(deactiveIcons[tab.getPosition()]);
        tab.setCustomView(HomeTabsAdapter.getTabView(deactiveIcons[tab.getPosition()],R.color.tab_inactive,"test",Home2Activity.this,tabs));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        //tab.setIcon(activeIcons[tab.getPosition()]);
        tab.setCustomView(HomeTabsAdapter.getTabView(activeIcons[tab.getPosition()],R.color.tab_active,"test",Home2Activity.this,tabs));
    }
}
```

**and Here is my adapter(`HomeTabsAdapter.java`)**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HomeTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    List<Fragment> fragments;
    List<String> tabTitles;
    public HomeTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments=new ArrayList<>();
        tabTitles=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String title){
        fragments.add(fragment);
        tabTitles.add(title);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static View getTabView(int imageId, int color, String title, Context context, TabLayout tabLayout){
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,tabLayout,false);
        TextView tabTitle=v.findViewById(R.id.tabTitle);
        tabTitle.setText(title);
        tabTitle.setTextColor(color);
        tabTitle.setTypeface(Utility.getFontTypeFace(context));
        ImageView icon=(v.findViewById(R.id.tabIcon));
        icon.setImageResource(0);
        icon.setImageResource(imageId);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

And the result is icons with fix color and also titles with fixed color. Nothing change with select and *unselect* the tabs. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:-

```
private void setCustomTab(TabLayout tabLayout, int index, String title) {
    TextView tab_home = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custome_tab, null);
    tab_home.setText(title);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(index).setCustomView(tab_home);
}
```

Use this above method like below:-

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
setCustomTab(tabLayout, 0, "Upcoming");
setCustomTab(tabLayout, 1, "Completed");
```

Comment: what is the difference between using this method and getTabView method in HomeTabsAdapter?